# how to nest javascript http request calls?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I am struggling to make a call that on button click, will pass a value to an http request.  The results of that first request are parsed out, and then used in a second http call.  I can get the first one call to work as:

```
 {
   import config from "../config.json";
   const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");
   ...
   let value1 = makeApi1Call(rawValue);
   let value2 = makeApi2Call(value1);

  makeApi1Call(rawValue) {

  let aValue = null;
  httpModule.request({
     url: url1+rawValue,
     method: "GET"
  }).then((response) => {
     let status = response.statusCode;
     if (status === 200) {
        let content = JSON.parse(response.content);
        aValue =  content[0].aValue;
        console.log("===>received aValue : " + aValue);
        return aValue;
      }  else if (status === 404) {
         console.log("===> returned [404] ... returning null " );
         return aValue;
      }
   }, (e) => {
      console.log("===> Error occurred " + JSON.stringify(e));
     return aValue;
   });
}
```

Naturally, because the http response finishes after the call to it, the returned value is null. I can see it in the console log, but it's too late to use.  I tried adding a callback method that would make my second http call, but I am not grasping it.  I am not sure if I should just make the second api call in my (status == 200) block, or is there a better "javascript" (which I am still learning) approach to this?

Comment: if `makeApi1Call` returned the Promise returned by `httpModule.request` then you could simply use a Promise chain

Comment: any chance you can elaborate?  I am really struggling with Promises, callbacks.  I get the concept, but I can't seem to put one together to save my life.

Comment: see how `httpModule.request({ ... }).then((response) => {` that's a Promise chain ... and `return` returns a value from a function

Comment: Just make your subsequent XHR call within the first then, after parsing the data, and before returning, I think

Comment: Learn all about Promises, you may use this [link](https://javascript.info/promise-basics). Once you understand promises it must be easy for you to handle the async requests.

Comment: where define url1 and rawValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  let value1;
  let value2;

  makeApi1Call(rawValue) {

  let aValue = null;

  httpModule.request({
     url: url1+rawValue,
     method: "GET"
  })
  .then((response) => {
      value1 = response.someData
   })
  .then(() => {
      value2 = makeAPIcall2(value1)
   }
```

I changed your code so that at least your second call does not fire until the first finishes.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to nest my HTTP calls this way and get results as desired.  I wlll also dig deeper into Promises per the link provided by @Manoj.